# GUI Animation - Roblox Studio

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

I already know how to use the tweenService. I am looking to see if there is a way to animate a user interface frame by frame.

Comment: Yeah, use TweenService. When you call `TweenService:Create(part, tweenInfo, goal)`, pass the UI element in as the first argument. TweenService works on all subclasses of Instance.

Comment: Ah , I see. I will look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like it was told in the comments, use the Tween Service. Here are 2 Articles about it

- https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/TweenService
- https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/GUI-Animations